# User.findOne is looping over in object destructuring string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, object-destructuring

I am going with an online course, there's a part where the instructor says he is trying to find/ validate a user using `User.findOne` and passes some conditions to find the requested user. To pass the value, he uses object destructuring. Heres the specific code:

```
const token = req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "");
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "secret key here!"); 

// issue is here, look at the second property of the findOne function's argument.
const user=await User.findOne({_id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token})
```

The instructor is using a string key in `'tokens.token'`. He's saying that, `mongodb` will loop over the all the tokens available in specified `user` object to check if the given `token` matches.

And if you are wondering, here's an example of a single `user` which contains **auth** tokens:

```
  {
        "name": "Prottay",
        "_id": "5e27f23b6b549b4c28b8ac35",
        "password": "$2a$08$gUfMwk6TNWViHihrcxjKg.8EXD04lLkGIWXqzrf8wYokdLQXHxpdy",
        "tokens": [
            {
                "_id": "5e27f23b6b549b4c28b8ac36",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTI3ZjIzYjZiNTQ5YjRjMjhiOGFjMzUiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk2NzYyMTl9.-PWXzlEoPlEZn9F_awtzqrXOtByxUCW9RCdchHF1yKE"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e280429596e742dcc2f9e30",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTI3ZjIzYjZiNTQ5YjRjMjhiOGFjMzUiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk2ODA4MDl9.7W-QZ55Cc3NFd_-NPyJ0VW_5F1UVrDWAV4xHX63D6tc"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e280435596e742dcc2f9e31",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTI3ZjIzYjZiNTQ5YjRjMjhiOGFjMzUiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk2ODA4MjF9.vppisFiNNC_DYHtGK0IURzEOCCC5zcWl1v9yD6l1D4I"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 3
    },
```

To me it looks like by using `'tokens.token': token` instructor is trying to loop over on the **user's tokens** array to match the correct token.

Am I right? If I am how can he be using loop in object destructuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructor is not looping over an array using object destructuring but using the `mongodb` syntax for searching for a document within an array where you do not know the index before hand.

> If you do not know the index position of the document nested in the array, concatenate the name of the array field, with a dot (.) and the name of the field in the nested document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. Your website has dark mode and it stays darkmode even after refreshing. How do you do that? Using localstorage to save the state?

Comment: Yep, using `localStorage` is one way of handling it, that's what I currently use. You can also add media queries for `prefers-color-scheme`. There a loads of articles on this topic when you google it.

Comment: I tried using localstorage, but somehow it isn't working, can you show me an example of code on how you set up your context for dark mode?

Comment: @ProttayRudra I just sent you an email